# Postgres Indices: how can they got lost (missing indices)?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a question concerning postgres-indices:

1. What "field" exactly is covered by an index?
   Is it correct, that indices are effective on columns? Does each field in the column then has an index?
   Is it correct, that all columns used in queries should have an index?
2. By comparison of seq-scan and idx-scan one can detect missing indices. What exactly is a missing index and how can they got lost?

Comment: This question is too general. An answer would require a basic course in relational databases. You'll have to do some reading! By the way, there are no "fields" in a database...

Comment: Depends on your queries. And an index is never missing, you created one or you didn't. You dropped one, or you didn't. Your choice. But first, get your queries clear and start using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to see the query plan and see where time is spent. With that knowledge you can start optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, not all columns should have an index. Indexes are for use on the columns that are used in filtering critera; ON, WHERE, HAVING. Generally, only the most selective column or columns should be used to define the index (and you can use more than one column). Now, some queries can benefit from adding columns to the INCLUDE clause of an index. But, that's not the same as making them the keys. The [basics for indexes are here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html).
2. Indexes aren't really missing. That's the optimizer making a suggestion for a candidate index. Don't assume it's correct. Test and validate the suggestion.